# zc.buildout cannot import name PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to resurrect old application and I'm using bootstrap script. I tried different versions of setuptools, but still the same error: (Default one for this script is 18.3)

```
zc.buildout.buildout.main(args)
```

leads to

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\bootstrap-win.py", line 165, in <module>
    import zc.buildout.buildout
  File "c:\users\horodysk\appdata\local\temp\tmpnpvxop\zc.buildout-3.0.1-py2.7.egg\zc\buildout\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning
ImportError: cannot import name PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning
```

I have Python 2.7.9 and not much packages installed, only:

```
setuptools (18.3)
wheel (0.24.0)
```

any ideas what can I do in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem.
This setuptools version is really old; the best version for Python 2 seems to be 44.1.1 ...

My suggestion would be:

- Throw away any ancient `bootstrap.py` you may have. If you have run it already, start over anew, recreating your virtualenv.

  - If recreating the virtualenv, be sure you have **committed and pushed** anything you want to keep!
- Look for any version specs regarding setuptools and zc.buildout in your
  `buildout.cfg`. You might add the following:

> ```
> [versions]
> setuptools=
> zc.buildout=
> ```

- Update your virtualenv: `pip install -U pip setuptools zc.buildout`
- run buildout.
- If your project setup doesn't work with with a recent `zc.buildout`, fix it.